# Is stutter-step considered a bug?

Tags: diablo-iii

Many Blizzard games allow to cancel animations, so units can move farther while shooting. Warcraft (DOTA) and Starcraft are good examples where you can invest APM to make your units more effective.

I found this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5h1I6J0Luuc) where some guy demonstrates this for the Demon Hunter. It seems very effective and you can move farther than "normal" kiting where you wait for the animation to finish.

Is this also considered a bug, like the [higher DPS with clicking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68644/is-there-a-difference-in-dps-depending-on-how-you-attack)? Should I bother to learn how to do this or will they fix it? I mean it is a bit unfair as melee characters do not have this option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference in DPS depending on how you attack?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68644/is-there-a-difference-in-dps-depending-on-how-you-attack)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, it's describing a different behaviour to the click/hold down bug.

Comment: I created both questions as I think they describe two different aspects of the same action. DPS increase is not a requirement for stutter step execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bashiok the D3 community manager already stated that they did it on purpose:

> It's an intentional mechanic, not an exploit or bug. Our intent is
> simply to make combat feel good and responsive, but the implementation
> to hit that goal in the closed beta build is actually quite old. It's
> likely you'll see changes within some future beta push that reflect
> more what we're testing now internally, but of course it's possible
> that won't be the final implementation either.<sup>[1](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3341754892#11)</sup>

Comment: Is there an equivalent for melee characters? I seems a bit unfair :)

Comment: It also work's for melee characters only that it's not as effective. Every attack with a little range on it can be "exploited" that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If the developers wanted you to be able to move a unit that far while shooting, they wouldn't have made it require cancelling an animation.  This is what's called an 'exploit'.

Comment: Do you have a source and will it be fixed? Exploits are not always a bad thing. I want to know if there are plans to remove it from the game.

Comment: @ayckoster Sorry, can't predict the future.  If it's not a major exploit, I would expect them to just leave it the way it is.